# Convert the form of two-dimensional PDE (Klein-Gordon equation)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

Convert the form of two-dimensional PDE (Klein-Gordon equation) from
$u_{ξζ}=\sin⁡ u$ to $u_{tt}-u_{xx}=\sin⁡ u$.

Using the assumption
\begin{align}
ξ&=\frac{1}{2} (x+t), \\
ζ&=\frac{1}{2} (x-t).
\end{align}

I tried to use the general solution for the wave equation
\begin{align}
 u(ξ,ζ)=u(x+ct)+u(x-ct)
\end{align}

From the assumption $x=ξ+ζ  ,t=ξ-ζ$.

Now,
\begin{align}
u(ξ,ζ)=u(x)+u(t)
\end{align}
\begin{align}
u_ξ&=u_x+u_t\\
u_{ξζ}&=u_{xx}-u_{tt}.
\end{align}
My problem is when I replaced it, I got this equation:
\begin{align}
u_{tt}-u_{xx}=-\sin⁡u
\end{align}
I don't know if I made a mistake or if there is another method that can be used.

I would like to point out that the same assumption should be used.

Comment: Multiply by $-1$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can slightly change your substitution and set $$\xi = \frac{x + t}{2} \quad \zeta = \frac{t-x}{2}.$$
For $u(\xi, \zeta) = u\left( \frac{t+x}{2}, \frac{t-x}{2}\right),$ we obtain
$$u_{tt} = \frac{1}{4}(u_{\zeta \zeta} + 2u_{\zeta \xi} + u_{\xi \xi})$$
and
$$u_{xx} = \frac{1}{4}(u_{\zeta \zeta} - 2u_{\zeta \xi} + u_{\xi xi}).$$
Then $$u_{tt} - u_{xx} = u_{\xi \zeta}=\sin(u).$$

Comment: Thanks, that is the correct assumption

Answer (score 1):

The sine Gordon should reduce to the pendulum equation

$$\partial_{tt} u(t) =-\sin(u(t))$$

for u independent of $x$.

$$\partial_{tt} u-\partial_{xx} u=(\partial_t-\partial_x)(\partial_t+\partial_x)u=\partial_{\xi\eta}u = -\sin u$$